# Uploading files to server in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I used File Transfer plugin in addition to File chooser plugin to get the URI of chosen file from the device but I always get 500 error from the server with exception of **'file'** you can check if you go to the [URL](http://darresny.com/file_transfer) of API.

Here is my .ts file constructor and method of attach:

```
export class ask {
  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http, public navParams: NavParams, private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File, public platform: Platform, private fileChooser: FileChooser) {}

  public attach() {
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: 'name.jpg',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      params: {
        "media_type": this.mediaType
      }
    }
    this.fileChooser.open()
      .then(uri => {
        console.log(uri);
        this.fileTransfer.upload(uri, 'http://darresny.com/file_transfer/', options)
          .then((data) => {
            // success
            console.log('upload success =>', data);
          }, (err) => {
            // error
            console.log('upload err =>', err);
          })
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like a server-side issue to me, are you able to send a file with Postman?

Comment: yes the problem was a server-side issue and it's fixed now thanks @Ivaro18